# How to Make a exe file run when user uninstall the application using InstallShield

Tags: installation, installshield, uninstallation, installshield-2015

I am New to InstallShield what i am trying to do is when the user Uninstall my application i want to run an exe to delete some file created by my application and uninstall a window service. I tried creating a custom action with condition REMOVE="ALL". Although i have no idea what this condition do.

Its so nice of you if anyone can provide some tutorial for InstallShield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows Installer's  ServiceInstall, ServiceControl and RemoveFile tables  (shown in InstallShield via the component advanced settings view )  you shouldn't need any custom actions.

Comment: BTW, the RemoveFile table is exposed graphically in the Files view now, since IS2014. (See "Support for Removing Files and Folders" in the [What's New](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/whats_newIS2014.htm).)

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for your reply but window service installation depends on the user weather or not he wants to install or not and the choice to user is provided under setting option within the application. My uninstaller.exe file checks weather the service is installed or not. if installed uninstaller performs its operation. Thats why i am looking for custom action makes my uninstaller exe runs when user uninstall my program

Comment: Why not make the windows service an optional feature in the installer and ask them if they would like to install it there? Either way my answer doesn't change.  MSI's ServiceControl table has the ability to stop and delete a service (during install or uninstall) that it didn't create. You don't need a custom action.  You can take that to the bank.

Answer (score 0):

If your installer installs a Windows service, it will automatically remove the service on uninstallation. Also, it will remove all files it created during installation. If you are willing to perform any other action or delete some other files, you need to invoke a Custom Action after uninstallation completes. That custom action can be an EXE file as you mentioned and you just need to configure the custom action and point it to the specific file to run. You can refer [How to pass parameters and invoke custom action](http://blog.e-zest.com/pass-command-line-arguments-from-installshield-or-msi-installer-to-custom-action-exe). Ignore the part to pass parameters. You won't need that. But it will give you an idea on how to configure a custom action or EXE to run during installation/uninstallation.

Comment: can you help me with the after which system event(Sequence) do i need to trigger my custom action.

Comment: There are several options in the event list. Can you post a screenshot? Probably you can fo that after "System Changes" event.